# Visual Studio 2015 hangs on deploying cordova application

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to build a blank cordova application into my iPad Air 2 with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition as i've already done it with success with the release candidate version.

I've got node.js v 4.2.2 on both machines since version 5.2.0 was hanging the build indefinitely, i've also got latest version of iTunes (12.3.1) as well as iOS 9.2 on the mobile device.

I've got the remote MAC set up and everything works fine for the building part, infact i've checked and the .ipa file is there at the end of the build into the folder `...\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bin\iOS\Debug` and if i launch that it will correctly install into iTunes and the iPad itself.

The problem is that the build action with Configuration "iOS" and "Local Device" with the iPad connected to the windows 7 PC will hang indefinitely after copying back said `.ipa` file after writing this line into the Build Output:

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
```

No matter how much time i wait it wont start the debug session even if i authorized the pc onto the iPad and have my web Inspector turned on onto the safari options. At this point i have to interrupt the build to be able to work again.

What really gets me is that if i connect the iPad to the MAC machine and build with "Remote Device" option the build works fine and i can debug remotely from my windows pc, unfortunately working like that isn't an option since the Apple machine isn't in the same room of my developing machine.

Any insight about this issue would be really appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: i didn't think Local Device was possible with iOS building and you had to always use Remote Device

Comment: It is actually possible, or at least it was with the Release Candidate version of VS 2015. What's more the build process doesn't end and keeps hanging at the deploying part so it suggests it should be possible to debug with a local device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a recent version of node and thus will also need to use a recent version of Cordova.

Specifically, you need to use Cordova 5.3.3 to be able to use Node.js 4.x.x+. The hang you are experiencing is exactly why.  It's an incompatibility with a down stream node module and Node 4.x.x.  You can downgrade to [Node 0.12.x](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/) or upgrade your Cordova project to 5.3.3.

http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/22/tools-release.html

Note that Node 5.x.x is only supported in Cordova 5.4.1.

Comment: The config.xml file sets the Cordova CLI version specifically to 5.3.3 like you suggested. I tried to build the project with Node.js 5.x.x but it resulted in the entire building on the apple machine to stall indefinitely with the status "undefined". I will try to apply today's "Visual Studio 2015 Update 1" and i will also try to downgrade to node 0.12.x and see how it goes.

Comment: Does the build complete but it stalls when deploying to local device?  If so, something might be going on specific to that feature and a recent iTunes update.  Note that debugging is not currently supported on local device but it should deploy successfully.

Comment: I couldn't make the "local device" build complete successfully but in order to work on the application i relocated the mac computer in the same room and built as "remote device". Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have worked around it, by making a simple build for IOS, Local Device. When the build completes, I locate the IPA file and double click it, then iTunes wakes up, and you can sync it to your device as normal. After this I decided to go for at bat script using msbuild and automatcally open the IPA file in iTunes after the build.

Answer (score 0):

This should be addressed in the latest VS Tools for Cordova Update 6.  Deploying to local device is now available.

Take a look at http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/02/04/announcing-update-6.html.